# Three monitors - shortcuts, mouse move

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I have three monitors, two side by side, the third widescreen above them. Left monitor is 1, right 2, widescreen 3. Is it possible move window from monitor 1 (or two) by mouse movement up? Or the same situation with keyboard? Now I have WIN+Shift+ left (right) shortcuts, is any way to change it to win+shift+up (down) or CTRL+xxx+num 1 (2,3). Thanks for ideas. (System Win10Pro,MB with 3 video outputs).

Comment: In Windows you can "arrange" the different screen so that they match the physical arrangement. Just drag and drop the monitors in the settings dialog as you want.

Comment: Yes, only now have I discovered that monitors can be stacked on top of each other, thanks for answer.